# ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with whitenoise

Tags: python, django, heroku

I am trying to deploy an app using heroku. But for some reason, the static files are not loaded with whitenoise and there is an internal server error message in the browser :

```
Internal Server Error 
The server encountered an unexpected internal 
server error (generated by waitress)
```

In the heroku logs :

```
ValueError: The file 'css/style.css' could not be found with 
whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0x7f5da0186750
```

Here are some points.

- an empty static file (with an empty robots.txt in) is created in the root folder for heroku.
- `python manage.py runserver` : everything works fine. no issue.
- `heroku local` 500 error. (but the view still shows up)
- css file path : `myhellowebapp/collection/static/css/style.css`
- both `python manage.py collectstatic` and `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic` work just fine.
- If I comment out `STATICFILES_STORAGE =
      'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`,
  the error message in the browser disappear and I can see html of the app in the browser, **but no css file is attached**

So it has to do with whitenoise but no I idea how to fix this.

setting.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

settings_production.py :

```
from hellowebapp.settings import *

...

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

wsgi.py :

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
    "hellowebapp.settings_production")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise

application = get_wsgi_application()
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(application)
```

I've been working this problem for days I tried all the possible solutions that I found online but none of them worked. Can anyone help?

The link to all of my code :

https://github.com/ryuji-the-dragon/hellomyapp

Comment: If you can publish your code online somewhere like github (with any secret credentials removed) I could take a look and work out what's wrong. Without being able to see all the files it's very hard to diagnose.

Comment: @D.Evans Thank you very much! This is the link to my code : https://github.com/ryuji-the-dragon/hellomyapp

Comment: The problem is that your `static` directory is empty, which means that git won't track it and so it doesn't appear on Heroku. So when the `collectstatic` command runs on Heroku it triggers an error. If you just created a file called `.keep` in the `static` directory and add it to git, everything should work.

Comment: Also, the version of the code you sent me was missing `__init__.py` files in `hellowebapp` and `collection`, but I guess these must be present in the real version otherwise you wouldn't get the app to run at all.